# Is "one in the same" only a bad transcription of "one and the same"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, dialects

> Trump suggested the lack of communication was justified because European countries don't inform him when they raise taxes on the US. 
>   "When they raise taxes on us, they don't consult us and I think that's probably ***one in the same***," Trump said.

[CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/03/12/politics/european-leaders-us-travel-coronavirus/index.html)

Shouldn't it be "[one and the same"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-and-the-same)? That's what I see when I look up the phrase.

Why do native speakers confuse the phrase? Is it for pronunciation?
Trump is a native speaker...is this a variation of the pronunciation of the  phrase??
[The original speech can be found here](https://theconservativetreehouse.com/2020/03/12/president-trump-remarks-with-ireland-prime-minister-varadkar-video-and-transcript/).

To me it sounds like "one 'n the same"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105497/discussion-on-question-by-rattler-is-one-in-the-same-only-a-bad-transcription).

Answer (score -1):

This was the subject of a previous thread:  ["One and the same" or "One in the same"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6748/one-and-the-same-or-one-in-the-same)

I agree the only logical construction is "one and the same" but I hear both frequently.

Comment: The question is more about the pronunciation, and transcriptions, not accepted construction.How do you know when they are saying "in" vs. "and". The distinction is almost impossible to discern.

Comment: The downvote is for claiming that this is a duplicate _in an answer_.